# JavaScript function is returning NaN

Tags: javascript, function, module, nan

I have a function and it is supposed to return a number but instead it is returning NaN. Here is the code

```
function priceCalc(cust, transit, passType){

    var price = 0;
    if (passType === "monthly"){
      if (cust === "student" || cust === "elderly"){
        price = transit.monthly / 2;
      } else if (cust === "transit worker"){
        price = 0;
      } else {
        price = transit.monthly;
      }

    } else if (passType === "pre paid"){
      if (cust === "transit worker") {
        price = Infinity;
      } else {
        value = prompt('How much would you like on your pass?');
        price = parseInt(value);
      }

    }
    return price;

  };
```

price is the variable that is supposed to have a number value when it is returned, for instance when I pass in student for the cust param, bus for the transit param(which has a monthly attribute which is 60), and monthly for the pass type param it should return 30, but instead I get NaN. I'm running a Jasmine test on it which is this

```
describe('the application', function(){
  describe('publicPrice function', function(){

    it('takes in customer status, transit choice, and pass choice to calculate a price', function(){
      expect(App.priceCalc('adult', 'commuter rail', 'monthly')).toBe(80);
      expect(App.priceCalc('student', 'commuter rail', 'monthly')).toBe(40);
      expect(App.priceCalc('elderly', 'subway', 'monthly')).toBe(35);
      expect(App.priceCalc('transit worker', 'bus', 'monthly')).toBe(0);
    });
  });

});
```

And the function is part of this module if that matters

```
var App = (function(){
  var Transport = function(mode, monthly, prepaid){
    this.mode = mode;
    this.monthly = monthly;
    this.prepaid = prepaid;
  };

  var commuterRail = new Transport('commuter rail', 80, 5);
  var bus = new Transport('bus', 60, 2);
  var subway = new Transport('subway', 70, 3);

  var customerStatus = prompt('Please enter your status. \nAdult \nElderly \nStudent \nTransit worker');
  var transitInput = prompt('Please select your method of transport: \ncommuter rail \nbus \nsubway');
  var passSelection = prompt('Please select a pass: \nMonthly \nPrepaid');

  var transitMethod;

  if(transitInput === "commuter rail"){
    transitMethod = commuterRail;
  } else if(transitInput === "bus"){
    transitMethod = bus;
  } else if (transitInput === "subway"){
    transitMethod = subway;
  }

  console.log(transitMethod);

  function priceCalc(cust, transit, passType){

    var price = 0;
    if (passType === "monthly"){
      if (cust === "student" || cust === "elderly"){
        price = transit.monthly / 2;
      } else if (cust === "transit worker"){
        price = 0;
      } else {
        price = transit.monthly;
      }

    } else if (passType === "pre paid"){
      if (cust === "transit worker") {
        price = Infinity;
      } else {
        value = prompt('How much would you like on your pass?');
        price = parseInt(value);
      }

    }
    return price;

  };

  var publicPrice = function(customerStatus, transitMethod, passSelection){
    return priceCalc(customerStatus, transitMethod, passSelection);
  };

  priceCalc(customerStatus, transitMethod, passSelection);

  return {
    // publicPrice: publicPrice,
    priceCalc: priceCalc
  };

})();
```

Comment: `App.priceCalc('student', 'commuter rail', 'monthly')` You're passing the string `commuter rail` for `transit`, instead of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`price = transit.monthly / 2;`

Here you are telling the interpreter to use property `monthly` of object `transit`. In your code `transit` is a string so `transit.monthly` evaluates to `undefined`

`undefined / 2` evaluates to `NaN`

I think you mean to pass in the variable objects you created instead of the string.

Comment: Haha I can't believe I didn't notice that Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`transit.monthly` is likely a String, you should parse it before you do calculus on it:

```
function priceCalc(cust, transit, passType){

var price = 0;
if (passType === "monthly"){
  if (typeof transit.monthly === 'string') {
    transit.monthly = Number(transit.monthly);
  }
  if (cust === "student" || cust === "elderly"){
    price = transit.monthly / 2;
  } else if (cust === "transit worker"){
    price = 0;
  } else {
    price = transit.monthly;
  }

} else if (passType === "pre paid"){
  if (cust === "transit worker") {
    price = Infinity;
  } else {
    value = prompt('How much would you like on your pass?');
    price = parseInt(value);
  }

}
return price;

};
```

Comment: Interestingly ... "60"/2 returns 30. I'd like to see the value of `transit.monthly` at runtime.

Comment: Number("60")/2 should play safer though

Comment: Javascript will automatically convert a string to a number when you pass it to an arithmetic operator, so this isn't the problem.

Comment: Indeed my bad, the problem comes from `undefined` as answered by lucky2id. Worth noting, `null / 2` seems to be `0`

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects three parameters:

```
function priceCalc(cust, transit, passType){}
```

In your tests, your passing a string as the second parameter `transit`, but the function is written as if transit is an object. So in your `priceCalc` function when you do:

```
price = transit.monthly / 2
```

price is set to NaN

It looks to me like the priceCalc function expects a `Transport` object.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string into transit, where you probably meant to pass an object of class Transport.

If you add this code (yours):

```
if(transit === "commuter rail"){
    transit = commuterRail;
  } else if(transit === "bus"){
    transit = bus;
  } else if (transit === "subway"){
    transit = subway;
  }
```

to the beginning of your function, it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code that converts the names of transit methods to their corresponding objects into the `priceCalc` function:

```
  function priceCalc(cust, transit, passType){

    var price = 0;
    if(transit === "commuter rail"){
        transit = commuterRail;
    } else if(transit === "bus"){
        transit = bus;
    } else if (transit === "subway"){
        transit = subway;
    }

    if (passType === "monthly"){
      if (cust === "student" || cust === "elderly"){
        price = transit.monthly / 2;
      } else if (cust === "transit worker"){
        price = 0;
      } else {
        price = transit.monthly;
      }

    } else if (passType === "pre paid"){
      if (cust === "transit worker") {
        price = Infinity;
      } else {
        value = prompt('How much would you like on your pass?');
        price = parseInt(value);
      }

    }
    return price;

  };
```

The code that you currently have that does this with the `transitInput` variable is useless, since that variable doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You get NaN because you try to divide "commuter rail" with 2.

`App.priceCalc('student', 'commuter rail', 'monthly')` -> `price = transit.monthly / 2;` where `transit` is *"commuter rail"*. You should probably use an object with a monthly property.

Comment: No, he's trying to divide `"commuter rail".monthly` by 2.